# Можно ли в python'е получить текущие настройки proxy Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, proxy

Делаю первые шаги в "python", надеюсь, что опытные программисты смогут помочь.

Есть следующая задача:

- для выгрузки нужной информации требуется "открыть" в "python" несколько десятков тысяч страниц. Написал код, который справляется с данной задачей, но после выгрузки не более 1000 страниц сервер разрывает связь (думаю, стоят ограничения на максимальное количество открытий страниц с одного ip).

Попытался добавить в код использование бесплатных прокси-серверов, но пока не преуспел в этом (как правило, все заканчивается тем, что прокси - сервера не могут установить связь с сервером сайта).

В то же время через "Chrome", в котором установлено расширение "Browsec", возможность заходить на сайт остается.

Возникает вопрос:

- можно ли в "python" подгрузить текущие настройки "proxy-сервера" из "Chrome", чтобы попытаться "скормить" их сайту, на который я пытаюсь зайти?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вообще так делать нехорошо, потому сайты и могут защищаться. Использовать Хрома нет надобности, настройте TOR и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Настройки прокси у Chrome берутся от общих настроек браузера в системе. Хранятся в реестре http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050262/change-browser-proxy-settings-from-python. Второй вариант http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: @1d0 +1, только не из "настроек браузера в системе", а из системных настроек. В случае с windows - действительно в ie те бе настройки. В случае с линуксом - тут зависит от рабочего окружения. Для Gnome, Unity, KDE - это тоже системные настройки. Для других - надо смотреть.

Comment: @1d0 Посмотрев первую ссылку, зашел в реестр HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
и обнаружил, в частности, параметр AutoConfigProxy, значение которого равно wininet.dll. Кстати, если зайти в настройки Chrome, то в блоке "Параметры прокси-сервера" написано, что "Этот параметр управляется расширением Browsec"
Если правильно понимаю, именно поэтому AutoConfigProxy = wininet.dll
Возможно, я неправ, но у меня создалось впечатление, что первым способом узнать текущие настройки прокси-сервера нельзя. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: p.s. еще обратил внимание на значение других параметров реестра из Internet Settings:
1. ProxyEnable = 0, 
2. MigrateProxy = 1